# Make an unbreakable block in TeX

Tags: latex, tex, page-break

I want to do something like the following in TeX:

```
\begin{nobreak}  

Text here will not split over pages, it will remain
as one continuous chunk. If there isn't enough room
for it on the current page a pagebreak will happen
before it and the whole chunk will start on the next
page.  

\end{nobreak}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to consider asking over at http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Cross-link for convenience: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could try:

```
\begin{samepage}
 This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. 
 This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. 

 \nopagebreak
 This the second. This the second. This the second. 
 This the second. This the second. This the second. 
 This the second. This the second. 
\end{samepage}
```

`samepage` prevents LaTeX from pagebreaking within one paragraph, i.e. within the `samepage` environment, pagebreaks are only between paragraphs. Thus, you need `nopagebreak` as well, to prevent LaTeX from pagebreaking between two paragraphs.

Answer (score 18):

A quick test reveals that`minipage` has this behavior, too.

```
\begin{minipage}{3in}
One contiguous chunk.
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{3in}
Another contiguous chunk.
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: One may also use `\textwidth` as the required parameter to minipage if you'd like to maintain the same width as the rest of the document: `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`

Comment: Also note that this doesn't work if there are floats in the minipage. The floats won't be constrained by it apparently.